# How to create infinite objects in a list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I am making a game in pygame and I want acorns to fall from the sky.

```py
class Acorn:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x  = random.randrange(0, 450)
        self.y = 0
        self.image = pygame.image.load("Images/acorn.png")

    def create(self, screen):
        screen.blit(self.image, (self.x, self.y))
        self.y += 1

acorns.append(Acorn)
```

Inside my game loop, I try and create multiple acorns

```py
for x in acorns:
    x.create(screen, screen)
    acorns.append(Acorn)
```

Comment: *Multiple* objects is not *infinite* objects.

Comment: What's going wrong? What do you need help with? Please specify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here we append a object to a list infinitely. Then we call the create function for each object in the list.

```
class Acorn:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x  = random.randrange(0, 450)
        self.y = 0
        self.image = pygame.image.load("Images/acorn.png")

    def create(self, screen):
        screen.blit(self.image, (self.x, self.y))
        self.y += 1
Acorns = []
while True:
   Acorns.append(Acorn(args))
   for ac in Acorns:
       ac.create(screen)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to create [Instance Objects](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#instance-objects) of the class `Acorn`:

```py
acron = Acron()
```

Create the `acorns` at random positions one after the other, delayed by an time interval. Use [`pygame.time.get_ticks()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.get_ticks) to measure the time and to compute the time when the next object has to be spawned:

```py
acorn_image = pygame.image.load("Images/acorn.png")

class Acorn:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x  = random.randrange(0, 450)
        self.y = 0
        self.image = acorn_image 

    def move(self):
        self.y += 1

    def draw(self, screen):
        screen.blit(self.image, (self.x, self.y))
```

```py
next_acorn_time = 0
acorn_time_interval = 100 # 100 milliseconds = 0.1 seconds

# applicaiton loop
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    current_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
    if current_time >= next_acorn_time:
        next_acorn_time += acorn_time_interval 
        new_acorn = Acorn() 
        acorns.append(new_acorn)

    # [...]

    for acron in acorns[:]:
        acron.move()
        if acron.y > screen.get_height():
            acorns.remove(acorn)

    for acron in acorns[:]:
        acron.draw(screen)
        if acron.y > screen.get_height():
            acorns.remove(acorn)
    pygame.display.flip()
```